# How to structure data in a React-based quiz?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write a quiz in React and have run into some issues. I've seen examples of quizzes written in react online, but they are based on each question having the same amount of inputs and looking the same.

My quiz needs to be different for each question based on the app I am trying to develop.

Per my code below, you can see how I currently am doing it - and it is working, but there's got to be a better way to structure this. Please help!

```
import tools from '../assets/tools.png'
import test from '../components/Questions'
import { useState } from 'react'

function SkillsCoach() {

    const [question, setQuestion] = useState(0)
    const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({})

    // array to hold question numbers and respective functions
    const array = [
        {
            Q: 0,
            Function: Start()
        },
        {
            Q: 1,
            Function: Question1()
        },
        {
            Q: 2,
            Function: Question2()
        }
    ]


    function Start() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-12 text-center mx-auto mt-5">
                        <h1 className="fw-bold">Skills Coach</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-4 text-center mx-auto mt-5">
                        <img src={tools} alt="" className='w-50' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-12 col-lg-10 text-center mx-auto mt-5" >
                        <a className="btn btn-success w-50 fs-2" onClick={() => { setQuestion(question + 1) }} >
                            Start
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }



    function Question1() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-4 text-center mx-auto mt-5">
                        <img src={tools} alt="" className='w-50' />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-12 text-center mx-auto mt-5">
                        <h1 className="fw-bold">What Emotion are you feeling?</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-12 col-lg-10 text-center mx-auto mt-5" >
                        {/* <a className="btn btn-danger w-50 fs-2" onClick={(e) => { setAnswers({ emotion: e.target.innerText }); setQuestion(question + 1) }} >
                            Emotion
                        </a> */}
                        {mapElements()}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    function Question2() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-12 text-center mx-auto mt-5">
                        <h1 className="fw-bold">Any Secondary Emotions?</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-4 text-center mx-auto mt-5">
                        <img src={tools} alt="" className='w-50' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-12 col-lg-10 text-center mx-auto mt-5" >
                        <a className="btn btn-warning w-50 fs-2" onClick={(e) => { console.log(answers.emotion) }} >
                            More Emotions
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    function mapElements() {
        console.log(test)
        return (
            test.emotions.map(emote =>
                <a className="btn btn-danger w-50 fs-2 m-2" onClick={(e) => { setAnswers({ emotion: e.target.innerText }); setQuestion(question + 1) }} >
                    {emote}
                </a>)
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {array[question].Function}
        </div>
    )
}



export default SkillsCoach
```

Comment: Do not put the answers in the quiz. Anyone with the React browser extension can view the live state. The quiz should be validated on the server. When you start a quiz, begin a session with the client, questions, and answers. When they submit, validate what they sent against the quiz session object.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It seems to be more of a survey than a quiz with correct/wrong answers. Also, it might not be necessary to hide it, if the developer doesn't mind the users looking into the code.

Comment: Have you checked this package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quiz-component

Comment: @SteffenAndreasKloster That's correct, it is more of a survey than a quiz in reality.

Comment: @DineshMsd that package looks promising, I will look into that

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little hard time reading and understanding your code. But instead of creating a function to each of your questions, you could store their data in a variable, and then go through them by the current index. Something like this:

```
import tools from "../assets/tools.png";
import test from "../components/Questions";
import { useState } from "react";

class Question {
  constructor(question, answers) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
  }
}

function SkillsCoach() {
  const questions = [
    new Question("What Emotion are you feeling?", []),
    new Question("Any Secondary Emotions?", []),
  ];

  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(null);

  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({});

  function mapElements() {
    console.log(test);
    return test.emotions.map((emote) => (
      <a
        className="btn btn-danger w-50 fs-2 m-2"
        onClick={(e) => {
          setAnswers({ emotion: e.target.innerText });
          setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1);
        }}
      >
        {emote}
      </a>
    ));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {currentQuestion === null ? (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-12 text-center mx-auto mt-5">
              <h1 className="fw-bold">Skills Coach</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-4 text-center mx-auto mt-5">
              <img src={tools} alt="" className="w-50" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-12 col-lg-10 text-center mx-auto mt-5">
              <a
                className="btn btn-success w-50 fs-2"
                onClick={() => {
                  setCurrentQuestion(0);
                }}
              >
                Start
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-4 text-center mx-auto mt-5">
              <img src={tools} alt="" className="w-50" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-12 text-center mx-auto mt-5">
              <h1 className="fw-bold">{questions[currentQuestion].question}</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-12 col-lg-10 text-center mx-auto mt-5">
              {mapElements()}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SkillsCoach;
```

Generally, you'd have your question data stored, stuff like question text and possible answers, and then show the current one dynamically, by calling the current question object, based on the current question index.

Comment: I think I understand what you are getting at. Could you show an example of how the questions would be stored in an object and rendered if each question is different?